# How to call more than one funtion in order to execute one after the other in android

Tags: android, multithreading

I am developing android application,i have a question how should i call more than one function in order to execute them one after the other

i have one asyntask in oncreate method

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
        {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
                location();
               return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {
            }
        }.execute();
```

In above code i am calling `location()`function Inside location function 
 I have some logic getting latitude and longitude value from database and through it in google map after completed this logic i am calling one more function from here itself

```
   public void location(){
     //first i am getting json value from DB 
     code/* */
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
     public void run() {
         //Those values are plotted in googlemap
           startTestThread1(); 
     }
    });
}
```

In above code First i am getting json from DB and display it in googlemap by using handler and also i am calling one more method called `startTestThread1();` 
My Problem:-
First i am calling location function after that i am calling  startTestThread1 function but  it is calling startTestThread1 function before completed location function 
My Requirement:-
it should call this `startTestThread1` function after executed `location` function

Comment: Move the thread-starting code to its own function and call that after you've called `location`.

Comment: please post the code where you're getting the JSON value from the DB. It sure is an async call so you might want to trigger the test after it returns

Comment: Why dont you use onPostExecute to update your map rather than creating thread in doInBackground using Handler?

Comment: @NullByte i tried as what you said but still i am not getting proper output

Comment: What is in startTestThread1()?